# Ribbon-style mesh particle question

Tags: bezier-curves

Heyo! I've been playing around with Blender for the creation of mesh particles, but I've run into an issue when using curves for "ribbon"-style meshes. If I want to control things like the taper towards the end of the ribbon, I'll have to convert the curve to a mesh and do manual edits (see below).

**Is there a good way to define things like taper along the curve, without converting it to a mesh?**

For context this is my current workflow:

1. Create a curve for the ribbon profile (typically just a single line or an "X" in this case)
2. Create a Bezier curve
3. Use the "x-curve" as bevel object in the Bezier curve
4. Convert the result into a mesh to edit taper towards the end

[image]

While this works okay for getting the shape, it means losing the curve controls and having to manually do the UV unwrapping, which is too much work to do-over if I ever want to change the flow of the curve later.

Comment: you can use a taper object for curves as well. (you could actually to it from the right click menu, or go into the curves settings)